# How to implement search dynamically with NativeSearchQueryBuilder()?

Tags: search, spring-data-elasticsearch

if userId is null ,I want to remove .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("createdBy",userId)) this condition, how can I implement search dynamically according to my passing parameters.

```
 public <T> List<T> search(String index, String type, String tenantId ,String userId, String queryString, Class<T> clzz){
    log.debug("==========search==========");
    String allField = "_all";
    MultiMatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(queryString, allField);

    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withIndices(index)
            .withTypes(type)
            .withQuery(multiMatchQueryBuilder)
            .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("tenantId",tenantId))
            .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("createdBy",userId))
            .build();
    List<T> list =
            operations.queryForPage(searchQuery,clzz).getContent();
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, *matchQuery* does not accept null value and throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [match] requires query value
```

*NativeSearchQueryBuilder* is an object like any other so you can build it after some additional preparation. Probably not the prettiest, but will do what you want:

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearch = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withIndices(index)
    .withTypes(type)
    .withQuery(multiMatchQueryBuilder)
    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("tenantId", tenantId));

if (userId != null) {
    nativeSearch.withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("createdBy", userId));
}

SearchQuery searchQuery = nativeSearch.build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: `QueryBuilder query = hasChildQuery(Province.CHILD_TYPE, QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", name.toLowerCase()), ScoreMode.None);
    List<Province> parents = operations.queryForList(new NativeSearchQuery(query), Province.class);
    return false;` . hasChildQuery can not be resolve, what class should I import?  @Joanna

Comment: Use `QueryBuilders.hasChildQuery(type, query, scoreMode);` from `org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders`

Comment: Is there a possibility of OR query? nativeSearch.withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("createdBy", userId)); nativeSearch.withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("assignedTo", userId));

Comment: If user matches with any one of them createdBy or assignedTo, I want result from ES.